# How to add more content in layout? is it possible to define more than 1 textview inside scrollView?

Tags: android-layout

This my code in this I have been using scrollView and inside it two textViews to add more content but it is working only when there is one textView please what changes i do to add more content?And here I want space between those textViews(content) but in my code i am trying for that but the content is overlapped and there is no proper space between contents.please help me..!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hp.kludge.AndroidActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="ANDROID"
            android:textColor="#f6080101"
            android:textColorHighlight="#df1425"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#e62027"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvC" />

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvWhat"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/tvC"
             android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
             android:text="What is Android?"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
             android:textSize="22dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Content"
            android:id="@+id/tvt" />

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/butNext"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#abc3fb" />


</RelativeLayout>
```